# Как найти целые корни числа?

Tags: c++

Как сделать, чтобы из последовательности выбирались только те числа, корни которых - целые числа. Т.е выводились только они. Например даны: 9, 3, 4, 6 выводились только 3,*,2,*. Только целые.

```
 if(...) cout << ...
```

Comment: Тут одним `if` не обойтись....

Comment: А как сделать?

Comment: можно, если вынести проверку в функцию.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Решение в лоб - используем банальную проверку

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
int r = (int)sqrt(a);
if (r*r == a) {
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Конечно, этот способ будет медленный. Но его можно ускорить, используя трюк. Известно, что квадрат любого натурального числа не может заканчиваться 2, 3, 7 и 8. Если числа приходят равномерно, то это сразу отсечет 40% чисел. Если использовать две последние цифры, то можно отсечь 78%. (для 4 последних цифр будет отсекаться 89 процентов, но нужно ли это?)

поэтому код чуточку улучшим.

```
while (пока есть что читать) {
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    int d = a % 10;
    if (d == 2 || d == 3 || d == 7 || d == 8) 
        continue;
    int r = (int)sqrt(a);
    if (r*r == a) {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}
```

Для того, то бы использовать это в if, заворачиваем в функцию

```
bool isSqrt(int a)
{
    int d = a % 10;
    if (d == 2 || d == 3 || d == 7 || d == 8) 
        return false;
    int r = (int)sqrt(a);
    return (r*r == a)
}
```

Ну и не забываем добавить в include  файл cmath

**upd**

если чисел много, и захочется чуточку ускориться, то вот возможные двухцифровые концовки для квадратов чисел

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 21, 24, 25, 29, 36, 41, 44, 49, 56, 61, 64, 69, 76, 81, 84, 89, 96]
```

но использовать лучше это в таком виде

```
int data[100] = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
if (data[a % 100] != 1)
    continue;
```

Comment: @KoVadim, а что в результате в `a` в 10 системе содержится?

Comment: а кто сказал, что это не десятичная система? Два последних массива эквиваленты. Я бы мог написать большущий if, который бы проверил все 22 значения. Но я делаю проще - я делаю массив на 100 элементов и записываю 1 там, где индекс соответствует значениям первого массива. Взяв значение по индексу я в один приход проверяю, попадает или нет оно.